# How can I make Kali Linux connect to Bluetooth on startup?

Tags: linux, keyboard, bluetooth, kali-linux

I've an old computer where I have installed kali linux on. The said computer has no built in keyboard so I have to use a bluetooth keyboard (I know I can just buy a wired keyboard but a wireless one is a lot more convenient within the context of my old computer.).

The keyboard, under normal circumstances, connects just fine after I've enabled bluetooth via `sudo service bluetooth start` and saw on the internet that I can automatically enable bluetooth via the `sudo systemctl enable bluetooth.service` command. It seems to have worked but it still cannot detect my keyboard on start-up, so I can't enter my username/password on startup without plugging in a wired one.

After I login, the bluetooth manager acts a bit weird as well, on the right side of the screen, I see small boxes saying "Bluetooth connected" and "Bluetooth disconnected" concurrently everytime I press a button on my keyboard. I have to manually go into the bluetooth manager and right click on the device and press "conenct" (Even though it already labels it as connected.)

My keyboard is new and I know for a fact that it works as desired on my other computers that are either ubuntu or windows, as a matter of fact the old computer in question used to has ubuntu as it's os and the keyboard in question was working just like I wanted it to, it only started malfunctioning when I've installed kali.

How can I make my keyboard connect on startup? Why is it acting weird?

Comment: Are u also use this keyboard for other devices? if yes, check [Arch Wiki - Bluetooth - Device_connects,_then_disconnects_after_a_few_moments](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Bluetooth#Device_connects,_then_disconnects_after_a_few_moments) for 2nd problem.

Comment: @test92995 Yes, that's probably it, it was connected to a different os in my computer before.